# Samba share inside other samba share

Tags: samba

Is there a way to put samba share inside other samba share? I have a share that have read and write permissions for all users and inside it i would like to put directory with read only permissions.

I tried this:

`[allusers]`
   `writable = yes`
   `path = /home/company/allusers`
   `force group = users`
   `comment = Directory for all`
   `valid users = @users`
   `read only = No`
   `create mode = 0660`
   `directory mode = 0770`

`[list]`
   `writable = yes`
   `path = /home/company/allusers/list`
   `force group = users`
   `comment = List of computers`
   `valid users = @users`
   `read only = yes`
   `create mode = 0660`
   `directory mode = 0770`

But without effect....

Answer (score 0):

It should be no problem at al to populate two shares in this manner.

However, the `[list]` won't be read-only, since your `writable` and `read only` are conflicting (actually they are [inverted synonyms](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smb.conf.5.html#WRITEABLE)). So, either setting `writable = no` or `read only = yes` will fix your issue.